# Lambda expression with Double Comparator

Tags: java, lambda, integer, double

How can I convert this expression:`(i1,i2) -> (int) i1 - (int) i2`
from int to double values.

I tried this:`(i1,i2) -> (double) i1 - (double) i2`, it's wrong.

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: can you show us the full code please

Answer (score 1):

This Expression

> (i1,i2) -> (double) i1 - (double) i2
> return a double.
> A Comparator must return an integer.
> A solution may be
> (i1,i2) -> (int)Math.signum(i1 -i2)
> for example
> List l=List.of(3.4,9.3,5.54);
> l.sort((i1,i2) -> (int)Math.signum(i1 -i2));

Notice that
(i1,i2) -> (int)(i1 -i2)
does not work because small number are rounded to zero.

Comment: Thanks, now I get this error:
 Operator '-' cannot be applied to 'java.lang.Object', 'java.lang.Object'

at the (i1-i2)-part

Comment: can you post the snipped of code, please, not only the lambda

Answer (score 0):

Do you understand the meaning of a comparator?
The main issue here (for numbers, like double or int), is sorting two elements (i1,i2) according to the compare function you decide.
Once you will return an integer positive value (common convention is returning "1"), it means the first object (i1) is larger. Once you will return a negative value (convention is "-1"), it meand the second object (i2) is larger. Once you return "0", it means that i1 and i2 are equals.
Now implement your sorting functionality in the comparator's compare function.

I guess that something like:

```
(i1,i2) -> return i1 > i2 ? 1 : i1 < i2 ? -1 : 0
```

should do the job.